# How to show that $\ell1$ is dense in $(\ell2, || .||_2)?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

How to show that $\ell_1$ is dense in $(\ell_2, || \cdot||_2)?$

I know that $c_{00}$ is dense in $(\ell_2, || .||_2)$ and also that $c_{00}\subseteq \ell_1 \rightarrow \ell_2 =\overline{c_{00}} \subseteq \overline{\ell_1}$

so, is this correct way to show that $\ell_1$ dense in $\ell_2,||\cdot||_2$?

can we use same logic to show that $\ell_1$ is dense in $(\ell_p, ||\cdot||_p) \; \forall 1\leq p < \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In general, if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \ell^p,$ then $(\tilde{x}_{n,k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\xrightarrow{\ell^p} (x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, where $\tilde{x}_{n,k}=x_{n}$ if $n\leq k$ and $0$ otherwise. Clearly, $(\tilde{x}_{n,k})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \ell^{p'}$ for any $p',$ having only finitely many non-zero terms. This proves density of $\ell^p\cap \ell^{p'}=\ell^{\min\{p,p'\}}$ in both $\ell^p$ and $\ell^{p'}$.